# jQuery callback after append

Tags: jquery, for-loop, load, append, jquery-callback

I have the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="body"></div>
```

JS

```
var site = { 'pageData' : [
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :   '#aboutUs',
        'url'           :   'aboutUs.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '.sectionInner'
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :   '#whatWeDo',
        'url'           :   'whatWeDo.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '.sectionInner' 
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :   '#ourValues',
        'url'           :   'ourValues.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '.sectionInner' 
    },
    {   
        'loadInTo'      :   '#ourExpertise',
        'url'           :   'ourExpertise.html',
        'urlSection'    :   '.sectionInner' 
    }   
]}

for(i=0; i < site.pageData.length; i++) {
    var loader = site.pageData[i];

    $('#body').append('<div id="'+ loader.loadInTo +'" class="section" />');
    $(loader.loadInTo).load(loader.url + ' ' + loader.urlSection);      
}
```

What I am doing is looping through the site variable and writing out some div's using jQuery's append method that have the id set in 'loadInTo', this works fine. After this is complete I want to use jQuery's load method to populate the divs with HTML from other pages. Is there a to make a callback after appending the div's? something like this:

```
$('#body').append('<div id="'+ loader.loadInTo +'" class="section" />', function(){
        $(loader.loadInTo).load(loader.url + ' ' + loader.urlSection);
    });
```

Comment: It should be `$("#" + loader.loadInTo).load(...);`

Comment: @ShadowWizard `loader.loadInTo` already has a hash-prefix, as shown at the question.

Comment: @RobW the appended HTML would be for example `<div id="#aboutUs" class="section"></div>` so still, as far as I know, `#` is needed before: `$("##aboutUs")` otherwise it would look for element with id of  `aboutUs`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I see. Instead of adding an extra sharp, remove the sharp using `.substr(1)`.

Comment: @RobW true, I was just giving the most straightforward solution, or at least fix for one glaring problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support a callback for `.append`. Also, it's much [more efficient](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly) to append the data at once, rather than calling `.append` for each element. See the code below.

Every element-to-append is added to a string. Once the string has finished, **a marker is added**, and the HTML is appended. Then, a poller is activated, checking whether the `marker` element exist in the DOM. If it exists, the poller is cleared, the marker is removed, and the code executes.

Update: `.substr(1)` is used when the ID is set, because the ID shouldn't be prefixed by `#`.

```
var toAppend = '';
var markerID = 'mark-end-of-append' + (new Date).getTime(); //Random
for(var i=0; i<site.pageData.length; i++) {
    var loader = site.pageData[i];
    toAppend += '<div id="'+ loader.loadInTo.substr(1) +'" class="section" />';
}
toAppend += '<div id="' + markerID + '"></div>';
$('#body').append(toAppend);
var poller = window.setInterval(function(){
    var detected = document.getElementById(markerID);
    if(detected){ //DOM is much more efficient
        window.clearInterval(poller);
        $(detected).remove(); //Remove marker
        for(var i=0; i<site.pageData.length; i++){
            var loader = site.pageData[i];
            $(loader.loadInTo).load(loader.url + ' ' + loader.urlSection);
        }
    }
}, 100); //Check 10x per second
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do appreciate it. I try what you have suggested.

Comment: @mtwallet I have just added an extra line. I noticed that `loader` wasn't defined at the first loop any more.

Comment: Thanks Rob tried it and it works great. Need some time to figure out exactly what's happening here. Once again thanks your your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why a callback?  Is `$(...).append()` an asynchronous call?  [I think not](http://api.jquery.com/append/), so why not just write another statement?

If what you're after is avoiding code-replication, you may create the new division in a temporary variable:

```
for( ... ) {
  var loader = ...;
  var newDiv = createDiv( {id:loader.loadInto } );
  $('#body').append( newDiv );
  $(newDiv).load( loader.url + ' ' + loader.urlSection );
}
```

Where the createDiv function may look like

```
function createDiv( settings ) {
  document.createElement('div');
  $(div).class("section");
  $(div).id(settings.id);
  return div;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do appreciate it. I try what you have suggested.

Comment: Append appears to be an asynchronous call, at least in Chrome.  My function afterward that tries again every 50 ms runs 10 to 17 times before append is finished with a long set of options built from an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you could use $() just after your appending contents code. This way you can be sure that the content is loaded and the DOM is ready before performing any tasks on the appended content.

```
$(function(){
//code that needs to be executed when DOM is ready, after manipulation
});
```

$() calls a function that either registers a DOM-ready callback (if a function is passed to it) or returns elements from the DOM (if a selector string or element is passed to it)

You can find more here 
[difference between $ and $() in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309791/difference-between-and-in-jquery)

http://api.jquery.com/ready/